# React Native - Footer button

Tags: android, ios, facebook, react-native, jsx

I am developing my [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) app with [Native Base](http://nativebase.io/). I have a simple login form as follows.

**View**

```
<Container>
    <Content>
        <InputGroup>
            <Icon name="ios-person" style={{ color: '#969696' }} />
            <Input placeholder="Email" autoFocus={ true} style={{ color: '#4b4b4b' }} />
        </InputGroup>
        <InputGroup>
            <Icon name="ios-unlock" style={{ color: '#969696' }} />
            <Input placeholder="Password" secureTextEntry style={{ color: '#4b4b4b' }} />
        </InputGroup>
        <Button style={ styles.loginButton}>
            Login
        </Button>
    </Content>
</Container>
```

**Styles**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  loginButton: {
    alignSelf : 'stretch',
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom:0,
    left:0,
    backgroundColor : '#4990e2',
    borderRadius : 0
  }
});
```

**Output**

[image]

How do I get the login button to be fully stretched at the bottom of the screen?

*PS : I am a beginner.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of `Content` element is calculated from it's child elements. In your case it gets just enough height to contain the two `InputGroup` elements, because the button has "absolute" position. You need to find your whole screen element first. Let's say it's the `Container` element. Then use "absolute" positioning on `Content` as well:

`position: "absolute",
top: 0,
bottom: 0,
left: 0,
right: 0,`

This way the  covers the whole screen. Then on your button element:

`position: "absolute",
bottom: 0,
left: 0,
right: 0`

I don't think `alignSelf` works for absolute positioning.